# How to return 401 page instead of login page when logged in user doesn't have permission

Tags: mvc, security, permissions

Currently, when a logged in user tries to access a page that they do not have permission to (because they don't have a certain role), Sitecore seems to redirect the user to the login page.

This is obviously confusing to the user as they are already logged in - I'd like to show a 401 page instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Background

When the `ItemResolver` processor executes, it determines the context item for the request based on the current URL. Additionally, it also performs a security check to see if the current user can access that item. If they can't, the context item is cleared and a `PermissionDenied` property on `HttpRequestArgs` is set to `true`.

When the `ExecuteRequest` processor executes, the `PermissionDenied` property is inspected and this is where Sitecore decides to redirect the user to the login page if one has been specified for the site. It does not determine if the user is already logged in or not when doing so, hence your problem.

#### Solution

You can achieve what you want by adding a pipeline step in-between the `ItemResolver` and `ExecuteRequest` processors in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline:

```cs
public class PermissionDeniedResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");

        if (args.PermissionDenied && UserIsLoggedIn(Sitecore.Context.User)
        {
            // Redirect to your permission denied page here
        }
    }

    private bool UserIsLoggedIn(Account user)
    {
        // Perform your logged in test here, e.g:
        return user.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

This can then be patched to execute after the Item resolver:

```xml
<processor type="MyProject.Pipelines.HttpRequest.PermissionDeniedResolver, MyProject"
patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
```